# Passing serialize Array to $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, post, serialization

I'm working with PHP and I trying to pass an array that is read with `foreach`, the array contains info by some users, I need pass this array to other view.

For example the `$info_users has (username: 'Miguel', username: 'Angel')`

In my first view I serialized the array: `serialize($arrayUserData)`

```
<?php
foreach($info_users as $users){
 echo "<p>".$users['username']."</p>";
}
|echo "<input type='hidden' name='ArrayUser' value='".serialize($users)."'/>";
?>
```

In my second view I unserialized the array: `$var = unserialize($_POST['Array'])`

```
<?php

$users = unserialize($_POST['Array']);
echo "<p>".$users['name']."</p>";

?>
```

The problem is that to show the info by the array just show the information to the last `user(Angel)`, but I need the info of the all users in the `foreach(Miguel, Angel)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serialize($infos_users["username"]);` would take all the username of the array, not only the last.

In your unserialize, use a `foreach` too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, were right, i needed serialize $info_users and use a foreach in my unserialize. :). Thank you very much!